# Flyway compatibility with Amazon Aurora

Tags: flyway

We use Flyway with our AWS RDS MySQL and Redshift instances, and it is working great!  We are considering switching from RDS MySQL to RDS Aurora. Amazon says that Aurora is MySQL compatible, but wanted to know if there are any known incompatibilities between Aurora and Flyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [AWS Aurora product details](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/details/):

> Amazon Aurora is designed to be compatible with MySQL 5.6, so that existing MySQL applications and tools can run without requiring modification.

Given that you're migrating from MySQL database, you won't even need to change the JDBC driver for the Flyway config. I have been using Flyway together with AWS Aurora for a while and haven't noticed any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with flyway, but here is main restrictions to use Aurora:

1. Aurora supports only InnoDB storage engine (MyISAM not supported), so your database should be compatible with it. For example, it means that maximum row size limited to 16Kb.
2. Geo spatial indexes are not supported