# Flyway compatibility with Amazon Aurora Global?

Tags: flyway, amazon-aurora

I understand flyway works with Amazon Aurora. Looked at some [threads here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636062/flyway-compatibility-with-amazon-aurora) and tried it as well. Im trying to understand if Flyway works with Aurora Global as well? We are trying to migrate to Global and this is a key consideration